# Cine.IO Alternative (Video Broadcasting)

Tags: ios, video, streaming, wowza, broadcasting

I'm trying to create a live one way broadcast. I'm looking for some type of software that can run on my server and then be broadcasted from a browser on my frontend site. Another requirement is that I can stream or view from iOS or Android. I've looked into wowza but I don't see a way to stream from a custom iOS App or from a browser.

Comment: Are you writing this because you're a former CineIO customer? So are we and looking for a similar turnkey solution.

Comment: @LaurentGorse yeah. Shame to see them go. They have a github full of open source libraries and I'm going to look into developing my own platform.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking our cloud-based solution, named: Bamboo, which support Live streaming from iOS and from browser. http://bamboo-video.com

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at alternate solutions like Justin Tv, Livestream,  Livon Tv live video streaming sites that include mobile apps.

If you want to build such project yourself, you will need software for site and also mobile apps because mobile browsers don't support plugins required for running such features reliably.

These articles provide solutions for building such project: [Clone Turnkey Live Broadcasting Site](http://www.turnkeyclone.com/twitch-tv-script-for-live-broadcasting/) , [Clone Meerkat Periscope App](http://clone-app.com/live-streaming-app-like-meerkat-periscope-ustream-livestream-younow/) .